# Prevent element jumping when error occurs

Tags: gui-design, errors

I'm working on a video editing application. It can have multiple layers and when a layer has an error, like corrupted frame, it displays an error message under the layer name. The problem is, when I play the video, the panel with layer names start to jump if there is an error: (the gif is just a simplified version of the UI)

[image]

What I tried before was:

- display the empty parent container even if there is no error, but then it looks strange because of the space:

[image]

- instead of whole message, display only an icon next to layer name and the message show in tooltip. This isn't good, because my users need to see the message directly in UI without any action (moving a mouse to an icon to show the message).

EDIT: I can't place the message next to the layer name. It's too long in some cases and it can produce the same jumping behavior.

Any other ideas how can I solve this jumping issue?

Comment: How frequent are these errors? And what does the surrounding UI look like? Do you have a screenshot? Is this a dense information screen? And as it plays, does it stop at the corrupted frame, or keep going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions as to how I would handle a scenario like this - top version changes to indicate an error and the user selects it to show, good for compact work interfaces, the bottom takes you larger version and provides feedback where it is ok or not, thus not expanding nor having empty space.

[image: Examples of interface]